# Is Polarity of atoms in propositional formulae uniquely defined?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

Given a propositional formula $\phi$, then positive/negative occurrence is defined as follows

$\bullet$  $\phi$ occurs positively in $\phi$

$\bullet  \neg \phi_1 $ occurs positively [negatively] in $\phi$, then $\phi_1$ occurs negatively [positively] in $\phi$

$\bullet$  if $\phi_1 \land \phi_2$ or $\phi_1 \lor \phi_2$ occur positively [negatively] in $\phi$ then $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ occur positively [negatively] in $\phi$

Assuming that the set of operators is $\{\land, \lor,\neg \}$, can we say that polarity of the atoms (positive/negative occurrence) is uniquely defined i.e if $\Phi_1$,$\Phi_2$ are equivalent formulae then the polarity of their atoms is the same?

Initially, I thought this is obvious because I could convert the formulae in negative negation form and all atoms occurring negatively are negative and all occurring positively are positive (also they can occure both ways in the same formulae ). But I was assuming that NNF is canonical, but then I realized it's not, and hence the question.

Comment: What do you mean with $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ being equivalent? Is it having the same truth table? If so, what exactly do you mean with the polarity of the atoms being the same? Here's the source of my confusion: Let $\Phi_1$ be $p\lor (q \land \neg q)$ and let $\Phi_2$ be $p$. The formulae are equivalent, but they have different atoms.

Comment: $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are equivalent means the same truth table. By polarity, I mean that in  $p \land (q \lor \neg q)$  $p$ occurs positively and $q$ occurs both positively and negatively. I think your comment answers the question in negative, the polarity is not uniquely defined.

Comment: The polarity is not uniquely defined because the polarity of an atom will simply be the polarity of the literal in its NNF form, but since NNF  is not canonical hence so is not polarity.